# Webpack top-level await not working: Module parse failed: Top-level-await is only supported in EcmaScript Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use webpack to deploy .jsx code to .js code and I do use top-level await in my code.

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const glob = require('glob');

const entries = glob.sync('./src/*.jsx').reduce(
    function (entries, entry) {
        let matchForRename = /^\.\/src(\/([\w]+))?\/([\S]+)\.jsx?$/g.exec(entry);
        console.log(matchForRename)

        if (matchForRename !== null && typeof matchForRename[3] !== 'undefined') {
            entries[matchForRename[3]] = entry;
        }

        return entries;
    }, 
    {}
);

console.log(entries)


module.exports = {
    mode: 'production', 
    entry: entries,
    output: { 
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, `public/__js`),
        filename: '[name].js',
    }, 
    module: {
        rules: [{ 
            test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/, 
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, `src`),
            use: { 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
                    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await"]
                }
            }
        },
        { 
            test: /\.css$/, 
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, `src`),
            use: { 
                loader: 'css-loader',
            }
        }]
    }, 
    resolve: { 
        modules: [__dirname + '/node_modules'], 
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'], 
    },
    experiments: {
        futureDefaults: true,
        topLevelAwait: true 
    },
    optimization: {
        mergeDuplicateChunks: true,
    }
}
```

My .babelrc:

```
{  
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await"],
    "comments": false,
    "compact": true
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

With this setup, I am getting the following error on every transpiled file:

```
ERROR in ./src/file_name.jsx
Module parse failed: Top-level-await is only supported in EcmaScript Modules
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: Top-level-await is only supported in EcmaScript Modules
    at /home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyDetectionParserPlugin.js:59:11
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:16)
    at JavascriptParser.walkAwaitExpression (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2320:29)
    at JavascriptParser.walkExpression (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2250:10)
    at JavascriptParser.walkMemberExpression (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2826:8)
    at JavascriptParser.walkExpression (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2283:10)
    at JavascriptParser.walkVariableDeclaration (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2104:33)
    at JavascriptParser.walkStatement (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1598:10)
    at JavascriptParser.walkStatements (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1459:9)
    at JavascriptParser.parse (/home/clauz/snake/site/dash/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:3353:9)
```

but I have the plugin installed and the experiment active, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is telling you you need to make your code into an [ECMAScript module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html). To do that you need to put `"type": "module"` in your package.json (as a separate thing) and then change your `require()` lines to `import` statements.